# Terminal Only Shows 1 Result when entering command ls?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm new to Terminal and I'm finding trouble navigating around files and folders. When I enter
`cd /Applications`, then `ls`, Terminal only shows 1 result when entering the `ls` command. Capo.app is all that shows up.

Why does this happen sometimes?

Comment: Are you typing `/Applications` or `Applications`? What is the output of `pwd`?

Comment: When does it ever not happen?

Comment: I think there are 2 versions of Applications... Now I realise..